# how add a listener for jtexfield when it changing?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField.` I want to invoke a function when the text in it is changed.

How do I do that?

Comment: Did you try `setActionListener()`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The appropriate listener in Java's swing to track changes in the text content of a JTextField is a DocumentListener, that you have to add to the document of the JTextField:

```
myTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    // implement the methods
});
```

Comment: It's a bit OTT when all one wants to do is detect a change, but I'll admit it's the only workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use Key Listener in this way

```
JTextField tf=new JTextField();
tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
        {
            if(!(ke.getKeyChar()==27||ke.getKeyChar()==65535))//this section will execute only when user is editing the JTextField
            {
                System.out.println("User is editing something in TextField");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
[Caret Listener](http://ra4king.is-a-geek.net/javadocs/javax/swing/event/class-use/CaretListener.html)

```
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {

        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
            System.out.println("text field have changed");

        }
    });
```

Comment: no, a caretListener is unrelated to changes of the _data_ ...

Answer (score -2):

You can add a KeyListener or a ActionListener to the field and capture events.

Comment: the values in field may change without user directly entering  the value int the field , for example setting the value in field based on the radio button selected.