# Is there an "onChange" for Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am relatively new with Java programming, and I wrote some code that places a JLabel, with the text set to "`Enter text here`" behind a JTextField. (Similar to the way the Microsoft Sign-in page functions) I would like to know if there is a way to delete the text of the JLabel when the user *begins* typing in the text field. (Or if such an event handler even exists.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443682/how-add-a-listener-for-jtexfield-when-it-changing

Comment: Typing "java jtextfield onchange" into Google produced a nice list of dupe questions with answers. Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield

Comment: I think you want an ActionListener...

Comment: What you want is a [TextPrompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/)-like component or [PromptSupport](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kschaefe/archive/2010/07/15/swingx-using-promptsupport)-from SwingX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic `onChange` function.  However there is a method you can define in a class that [`implements KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) which is [`public void keyPress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html).  You would use this something like the following:

```
public class MyClass implements KeyListener {

    private JTextField myField;
    private JLabel myLabel;

    public MyClass() {
        myLabel = new JLabel("Enter text here");
        myField = new JTextField();
        myField.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPress(KeyEvent e) {
        myLabel.setText("");
    }
}
```

There is of course a lot more flexibility you can add to this, but the above is the general idea.  For example, you could make sure that the `KeyEvent` is coming from the appropriate source, as rightly you should:

```
@Override
public void keyPress(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == myField) {
        myLabel.setText(""):
    }
}
```

... and lots of other stuff.  Have a look at [Oracle's Event Listener tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html).

Comment: This won't work. First off, `addActionListener(this)` requires your class to implement `ActionListener`, not `KeyListener`. Second, you would be better off implementing `FocusListener` for this problem.

Comment: @NathanielJones You're right, it should be `addKeyListener`.  My mistake, typing this up at work, haha.  And you're wrong about the `FocusListener`, since the OP explicitly says `I would like to know if there is a way to set the text to "" when the user starts typing in the text field`.  
W

Answer (score 2):

for some specific fields backed by a Document you can have a document change listener as shown here:

[Value Change Listener to JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield)