# Action listener for a JTextField to change value in another textfield

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have two JTextfields, I want the value/text of second Textfield to change based on any change in value/text made in first TextField

Here is what I am doing

```
    textField_15 = new JTextField("100");
    textField_15.setEditable(false);
    textField_15.setColumns(10);
    textField_15.setBounds(161, 253, 86, 20);
    panel_3.add(textField_15);

    textField_14 = new JTextField();
    textField_14.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int az = Integer.parseInt(textField_14.getText());
            int aw = Integer.parseInt(textField_15.getText());
            int aq = aw - az;
            String ar = String.valueOf((aq));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, az + " " +aw + " " + aq + " " + ar);
            textField_15.setText(ar);
        }
    });
    textField_14.setColumns(10);
    textField_14.setBounds(426, 186, 86, 20);
    panel_3.add(textField_14);
```

Comment: So far nothing is happening when I make changes in the field

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: don't use `actionlistener` use `document listner`

Comment: I assume you understand that the `ActionListener` won't be triggered until the user presses the `[Enter]` key

Comment: @FastSnail Except there is a difference between `10` and `1` and `0`...

Comment: I believe a similar question was answered here 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443682/how-add-a-listener-for-jtexfield-when-it-changing

Comment: @MadProgrammer 10 and 1 and 0 ?? hmm what?

Comment: @FastSnail A `DocumentListener` will tell you when I type `1` and `0`, not that the value is `10` ;) (ps I do see your point though ;))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't understand that `ActionListener` will only be notified when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key...

That would be the easiest solution, if, however, you want to monitor changes to a text component, you should use a `DocumentListener`

See [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details

This, however, raises some issues.  When do you assume the user has stopped typing?

There is a significant difference between `100` and `1` and `0` and `0`, so what we need is someway to defer the event notification to some time in the future, where we can "assume" that the user has stopped typing (or at least long enough for us to grab a reasonable value)

```
public class DeferredDocumentChangedListener implements DocumentListener {

    private Timer timer;
    private List<ChangeListener> listeners;

    public DeferredDocumentChangedListener() {

        listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
        timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireStateChanged();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
        if (!listeners.isEmpty()) {
            ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
            for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.stateChanged(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        timer.restart();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        timer.restart();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        timer.restart();
    }

}
```

Okay, so, this is a little trick.  This is a simple observable `DocumentListener`, which provides event notification at some point in the future that the document has changed.  In your case, you don't really care about the change, just that it has.

This sets up a non-repeating Swing `Timer` with a short delay (250 milliseconds in the example) which if it's not reset for that period of time, will notify any registered `ChangeListener`s.  If, however, the `Document` is modified within that time period, the `Timer` is reset.

You may want to play around with the "time out" value ;)

Which you could then use something like...

[image: Sum it]

```
JTextField number = new JTextField(5);
JTextField sum = new JTextField("0", 5);

setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

add(number, gbc);
add(sum, gbc);

DeferredDocumentChangedListener listener = new DeferredDocumentChangedListener();
listener.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(sum.getText());
        int result = num1 + num2;
        sum.setText(Integer.toString(result));
        number.selectAll();
    }
});

number.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
```

This, obviously doesn't provide any validation, so it could throw an exception if the text is not a number, but I'll leave that for you to figure out

You may also want to have a look at [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) which provide post validation process which can help validate the user input.

You could also use a `DocumentFilter` to further restrict what the user can enter, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details