# How to do not display data from the database at starting?

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, awt

I do not want to display all data from the database at starting. I want to just leave everything blank **until user does not type anything** in the textbox. Like searching. Please, someone, help me with that.

```
private void tKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                              
    //keyboard searching
    try{
        javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel dtm=
            (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel)rTable.getModel();
        int rc=dtm.getRowCount();
        while(rc--!=0){
            dtm.removeRow(0);
        }
        dtm.setRowCount(0);
        String n=t.getText();
        db.dbConnect.getUsers.setString(1,"%"+n+"%");
        ResultSet rs=db.dbConnect.getUsers.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            java.util.Vector row=new java.util.Vector();
            row.add(rs.getInt("cid"));
            row.add(rs.getString("name"));
            row.add(rs.getString("gender"));
            row.add(rs.getDate("dob"));
            row.add(rs.getString("country"));
            row.add(rs.getString("address"));
            row.add(rs.getString("language"));
            dtm.addRow(row);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using a DocumentListener and Swing Timer to manage the input monitoring, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955193/how-to-start-a-function-after-stop-typing-in-a-jtextfield-in-java/31955279?r=SearchResults#31955279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a DocumentListener to your textfield and check if the length of the textfield is more than X threshold.

Note: Just like what [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) said you want to add a timer to avoid too many calls to the database.

Thanks [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) for pointing that out.

```
       JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

            DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    onTextChange();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    onTextChange();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    onTextChange();
                }

                public void onTextChange() {
                    String text = textField.getText();
                    if(text.length() > 0){
                         // display the data
                    }
                }
            };

            textField .getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
```

Comment: Just note, that each time the user types, you’ll be hitting the database, which could introduce a undesirable lag in the ui and a large number of queries hitting the database. You might want to introduce a short delay of idleness before executing then functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to fetch data when user hits `Enter` (like in some search applications), then you can simply add an `ActionListener`.

```
JTextField searchField = new JTextField(20);
searchField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    System.out.println("Fetch data");
  }
});
```